# How to use HttpSerletRequest in Spring Boot 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, thymeleaf

Please help me!

I can edit the URL of the page like "?key=value", then reload the page and see the result. But how to set params and reload when clicking on a tag?

```html
<option value=""><a th:href="${'/?&sortByPrice=ASC'}">Giá từ thấp đến cao</a></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you put the wrong symbols in the URl.

you should use `?` with the fist key/value and then use the `&` 
Like this

```
/?sortByPrice=ASC&sortByvalue=none
```

OR

```
/abcd?sortByPrice=ASC&sortByvalue=none`
```